# Laravel validation required_without for media file

Tags: php, laravel-7, laravel-nova

I'm using media library for file field.
I have a two fields custom_url and media field in my form which either custom_url OR media need to be filled.

I'm validating the form using laravel request validation and the required_without rule, which looks like this.

I'm using nova package.

```
Text::make(__('Custom Url'), 'custom_url')
                ->rules('required_without:file')
                ->help('Required without file upload'),

Files::make('File', 'file')
                ->rules('required_without:custom_url')
                ->help('Required without Custom URL'),
```

I am uploading file but although it's showing me error always **Custom URL is required**.

I think file field is returning null value. Can anyone please guide me that how may I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your migration table and also store method.
Then look at the form field name and migration column name is as same or not.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably you are missing `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form declaration.

So it has to be `<form method="..." action="..." enctype="multipart/form-data">`